# Evenly placed Skip pointers

Tags: python, linked-list, skip-lists

I was reading about skip pointers and someone suggested that it is best to put evenly spaced sqrt(len of list) skip pointers. Can someone tell me what "evenly spaced" means here? I will also like to see the code of doing such a thing in Java or Python

Comment: Unless you have a *very* specialised problem don't even think of using linked lists in Python.

Comment: I was using the list ds in python

Comment: He meant implementing your own *list data structure. Python's own built-in `list` is, for most cases, good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think your friend was talking about [skip lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).  Usually the skip pointers are placed randomly through the list.  Evenly spaced pointers refers to deterministically spacing them throughout the list instead of randomly placing them.  Such a scheme would probably give faster reads, but would probably require more calculation when writing to the list.

Comment: I was specifically referring to "evenly spaced" pointers, not random

Comment: @user465983:  Yes, I mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_skips(posting_list):
post_list_with_skips = []
skip_count = math.floor(math.sqrt(len(posting_list)))
pos_index = 0
skip_period = math.floor(len(posting_list) / skip_count)
# -1 because of list indexing starts with 0
skip_index = skip_period - 1
while pos_index < len(posting_list):
    if pos_index == skip_index:
        post_list_with_skips.append([posting_list[pos_index], 1])
        skip_index += skip_period
    else:
        post_list_with_skips.append([posting_list[pos_index], 0])
    pos_index += 1
return post_list_with_skips
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).